# Найти y при разных условий x

Tags: c#, математика

Найти `y`, используя цикл (`for`) c диапазоном от 1 до 12 и шагом цикла 0.3, при том что:

- x < 2 уравнение y = x + 1
- 2<x<7 уравнение y=x в степени *3*
- x<7 уравнение y = x в степени *2* + 2

Я написал такой код:

```
Console.WriteLine("найти y");
double y = 0;
double a1 = 0;
double a2 = 0;
double a3 = 0;
for (double x = 1; x <= 12; x += 0.3)
{
    if (x < 2)
    {
        y = x + 1;
        a1 = y;
    }
    else if (x >= 2 && x <= 7)
    {
        y = Math.Pow(x, 3);
        a2 = y;
    }
    else
    {
        y = Math.Pow(x, 2) + 2;
        a3 = y;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("y при x<2 = {0}\n y при 2<x<7 = {1}\n y при x<7 = {2}", a1, a2, a3);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но я не уверен, что вывод сделан корректно, как мне сделать его более правильным?

Comment: `Но я не уверен, что вывод сделан корректно` какие то конкретные сомнения?

Comment: да, если добавить вывод переменной y в каждом if или if else то можно увидеть что он выводит дополнительные числа, я это имею в виду

Comment: а, ну это да, у вас же в задании - найти y при x в диапазоне [1,12] с шагом 0.3 - это значит, для каждого х в этом диапазоне найти y - то есть выводить y вроде как надо внутри for на каждую итерацию.

Comment: Ну по сути вы выводите значение `y` при `x=1.9`, `x=7` и `x=11.8`. Если вы хотите не этого, то опишите в каком виде вы хотите результат

Comment: да, если добавить вывод переменной y в каждом if или if else то можно увидеть что он выводит дополнительные числа, я хочу что бы он выводил все числа, но без повторения. По сути мне нужно что бы вывод не циклился в цикле

Comment: Вычислили y - вывели его. Всё. Откуда повторения?

Answer (score 3):

Надо что-то вроде

```
for (double x = 1; x <= 12.01; x += 0.3)
{
    if (x < 2)
    {
        y = x + 1;
    }
    else if (x <= 7)
    {
        y = x*x*x;
    }
    else
    {
        y = x*x + 2;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("x = {0}  y = {1}\n", x, y);
}
```